# MSSQL Mail permission was denied xp_sysmail_activate

Tags: sql-server, email

On MSSQL 2016 I can see error in SQL Server Logs.

```
Message
The activated proc '[dbo].[sp_sysmail_activate]' running on queue 'msdb.dbo.ExternalMailQueue' output the following:
'The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_sysmail_activate', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.'
```

Please, where is problem?

Comment: refer to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35924/sql-server-database-mail-why-cant-i-run-an-execute-against-xp-sysmail-activat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I set Security Policy Line on MSSQL 2016 I changed owner DB MSDB.
It is not possible. I returned owner back to login sa, all works.